# Mailboxer - get nth last messages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mailboxer

I am using Mailboxer on my Rails app, and don't want to get all messages in an conversation at once. How can I only get the last N messages in an conversation?

Answer (score 0):

I have never used Mailboxer, but looking at the docs and code it should be possible to limit messages using regular ActiveRecord methods.

Given a `conversation`, this would get the last 10 messages:

```
conversation.messages.order('created_at DESC').limit(10)
```